# Quartz Non-Stateful Job Persisting State

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am learning the Quartz Job Scheduler framework (using version 1.5.2 in jboss 5.1). I'm trying to understand the difference between stateful and non-stateful jobs.

It is documented that in any changes made in JobDataMap during job execution will not be persisted over the next execution of the job for non-stateful jobs, but the same will be persisted in stateful jobs.

To test the above I have written a non-stateful job in which the JobDataMap is being modified during execution of the job.  Per the above logic the changes should not be persisted or available during next execution of the job.
However, it does appear that the changes are being persisted through the execution of the job.

Here is the job class:

```
 public class QuartzTask implements Job{

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg) throws JobExecutionException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        System.out.println(arg.getTrigger().getName()+"  task executed:"+timeStamp);

        System.out.println("before put:"+arg.getMergedJobDataMap().get("data"));
        arg.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap().put("data", "added");
        System.out.println("after put:"+arg.getMergedJobDataMap().get("data"));         
    }    
}
```

If I execute the above job 2 times, then the output should appear as such:

> before put:null
>
> after put:added
>
> before put:null
>
> after put:added

However, the output looks like this instead:

> before put:null
>
> after put:added
>
> before put:added
>
> after put:added

What am I missing here that's causing this behavior?

Comment: I'm not an expert on version 1.5.2 but I think it's because you're using getMergedJobDataMap. If you use getJobDetail().getJobDataMap() your output should be the desired one.

Comment: I have tried with that one as well. same result.